# decimal to binary conversion error

Tags: c, binary, decimal

I am trying to create a program that converts decimal to binary and prints 0b before the binary.

I need the program to print 0b0 if 0 is the input, and 0b11101 when input is 29. I can seem to do one, but not the other, and when I fix that bug, the other stops working

Where am I going wrong ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{

int n,i = 0,j=0,k;

scanf("%d",&n);
int bin[100];

    k=n;

    //printf("n is %d \n",n);
    while(n!=0)
    {
        //printf("n is %d :\n",n);
     bin[i]= n%2;
        //printf ("n/2 is  %d\n",n%2);
     n=(n-n%2)/2;
     i++;
        //printf("i is %d\n",i);
    }
printf("0b");
    //if (n='0')
    //{
    //  printf("0");
    //}


    //else
    //{
        for (j=i;j>0;j--)
        {
            //printf("\n j is,%d and there ,is %d\n",j,bin[(j-1)]);
            printf("%d",bin[(j-1)]);

        }
    //}

}
```

Comment: Can you show me current output??

Comment: I have posted an answer, check and let me know if you get any problem.

Comment: [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)
[How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

0 does not need to be treated as a special case.  Simply fix: use a `do` loop rather than `while ()`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
  int n,i = 0,j=0,k;
  scanf("%d",&n);
  int bin[100];
  // k=n;  // not needed

  // while(n!=0) {
  do {
    bin[i]= n%2;

    // Another simplification
    // n=(n-n%2)/2;
    n /= 2;

    i++;
  } while (n);
  printf("0b");
  for (j=i;j>0;j--) {
    printf("%d",bin[(j-1)]);
  }
}
```

Other coding needed to handle `n<0`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
int n,i = 0,j=0,k;
scanf("%d",&n);
int bin[100]; 
k=n;
    while(n!=0)
    {
     bin[i]= n%2;
     n=(n-n%2)/2;
     i++;
    }
printf("0b");
    if (k==0)
    {
      printf("0");
    }
    else
    {
        for (j=i-1;j>=0;j--)
        {
            printf("%d",bin[(j-1)]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you should print `"0b0"` in the case `k == 0`, and not `0`. Also, why to do decimal conversion again with the `%d` format in printf.  Have you plenty of cpu resources to waste?

Comment: @LuisColorado, I have given `k==0` only, Can u check it once again?? And for printf what should I use??

Comment: for `printf(...);` you can use `fputc(bin[j-1] ? '1' : '0', stdout);`  This only makes one boolean test to select which character to print out.  I didn't see the `printf("0b");` prefix before the test for `k == 0`, so my apologies for the flame.

Answer (score 0):

A naive and more portable implementation of a decimal to binary conversion function ...

```
#include <limits.h>

void print_binary(unsigned x){
    unsigned n=UINT_MAX;

    n = ~(n >> 1);

    while (n){ 
        if (n & x)
            putchar('1');
        else
            putchar('0');
        n = n >> 1;
    }
    putchar('\n');
}
```